# Coloring Google Heat Maps in different colors

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I was trying to develop a heat following the Google Map API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) My requirement here is to color different points in the heat map with different colors. For example I want color some locations with red and some locations in blue. Is there a way to change colors of different points in Google Heat map ?